# Creating an array of objects inside an object that already exists

Tags: javascript, .net, object

I can create nested objects in Javascript like this:

```
var filter = {
    filterColumns: {
        value: "",
        valueText:""
        }
    };
```

but how can I turn filtercolumns into an array of objects? for example I would like to be able to do this:

```
filter.filterColumns[26].value = "value"
filter.filterColumns[26].valueText = "Bob"
filter.filterColumns[32].value = "value"
filter.filterColumns[32].valueText = "Ibb"
etc.
```

Thanks

EDIT: Apologies, I got this completely wrong. My original post confused javascript with C#. I have re-written it to reflect what I am trying to do.

Comment: This may provide a better description https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types

Comment: Have you seen real and working examples of C# code like that somewhere? If yes can you point us where and in what context? Or are you just asking if you can write code like that?

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot, I meant javascript not C#! I will edit the above right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
var filter = {
    filterColumns: [
        {
            value: "1",
            valueText: "Alice"
        },{
            value: "2",
            valueText: "Bob"
        },{
            value: "3",
            valueText: "Charlie"
        }
    ]
};
```

Now `filter.filterColumns[1].valueText` would contain the string `"Bob"`;

You can for example add to the list with the following code:

```
filter.filterColumns.push({value: "4", valueText: "Daniel"});
```

Comment: Yes thank you. But what if I want to add a value straight to 'filter.filterColumns[32].value' without having to add a value to the first 31 elements of the array?

Comment: @NickyLarson If I'm not completely mistaken, you can simply write `filter.filterColumns[32] = {value: "32", valueText: "Yoshi"}`. The term you may be looking for is "sparse array".